# MusicVAE fine-tune pre-trained model?

Tags: transfer-learning, fine-tuning, magenta, google-generativeai

Is there a way to start training MusicVAE from existing pre-trained models from Magenta?

https://magenta.tensorflow.org/music-vae
https://github.com/magenta/magenta/tree/main/magenta/models/music_vae#training-your-own-musicvae
https://magenta.tensorflow.org/performance-rnn
https://github.com/magenta/magenta/tree/main/magenta/models/performance_rnn#train-and-evaluate-the-model

I already tried training Performance RNN from Magenta and they had input flag warm_start_bundle_file where you could put existing pre-trained model. But I don't see anything similar I can do for MusicVAE existing models?

Mentioned warm_start flag:
https://github.com/magenta/magenta/blob/548dc4e2e6a8e3ac65e1921bd94fe589d661d47b/magenta/models/performance_rnn/performance_rnn_train.py#L40